Why does RingBuffer deadlocks after adding Condition to notify when new data arrived
I need a ring buffer that holds time stamped numpy arrays, it can be appended to, and it can be asked to retrieve all the arrays that were added after a certain time.
It worked correctly up until I added multiprocess.Condition to avoid the retrieve function returning an empty list if nothing was added after the last call (just block until at least one new entry was written).
Once I added my event, it stopped working, since reading the event condition requires the lock, but appending also requires the same lock.
Here's my code:
from typing import NamedTuple, List
import multiprocessing
import ctypes

import numpy as np

class TimedData(NamedTuple):
    t: float
    val: np.ndarray


class RingBuffer:
    def __init__(self, size: int, dim: int):
        self._dim = dim + 1
        self._size = size
        self.buffer = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_float, size * self._dim)
        self.np_buffer = np.frombuffer(self.buffer.get_obj(), dtype=np.float32)
        self._head = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
        self._count = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        self._data_added = multiprocessing.Condition(self.lock)

    def append(self, data: TimedData):
        assert data.val.size == self._dim - 1
        with self._data_added:
            head = self._head.value
            self.buffer[head] = data.t
            self.np_buffer[head + 1:head + self._dim] = data.val[:]
            self._head.value = (head + self._dim) % (self._size * self._dim)
            if self._count.value < self._size:
                self._count.value += 1
            self._data_added.notify_all()

    def get_measurements_after_time(self, t: float) -> List[TimedData]:
        def has_new_data():
            latest_idx = (self._head.value - self._dim) % (self._size * self._dim)
            return self._count.value > 0 and self.buffer[latest_idx] > t

        with self._data_added:
            self._data_added.wait_for(has_new_data)

            head = self._head.value
            count = self._count.value

            num_items = count
            left, right = 0, num_items
            offset = 0 if num_items < self._size else head

            while left < right:
                mid = (left + right) // 2
                idx = (offset + mid * self._dim) % (self._size * self._dim)
                if self.buffer[idx] > t:
                    right = mid
                else:
                    left = mid + 1

            result = []
            for i in range(left, num_items):
                idx = (offset + i * self._dim) % (self._size * self._dim)
                result.append(
                    TimedData(
                        t=self.buffer[idx],
                        val=np.array(self.np_buffer[idx + 1:idx + self._dim], copy=True)
                    ))
            return result


Here's some usage example:
# Track time for ensuring the test runs for 2 minutes
TEST_DURATION = 12  # seconds
APPEND_INTERVAL = 0.0001  # 0.1 ms
PROCESS_INTERVAL = 0.0001  # 0.1 ms


def append_measurements(buffer: RingBuffer,
                        stop_event: multiprocessing.Event,
                        timestamps: multiprocessing.Manager().list):
    """Process that appends measurements every 0.001 seconds."""
    start_time = time.time()

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        # Incremental time to simulate real-time measurement (here we just use time.time)
        t = time.time() - start_time
        data = np.array([random(), random(), random()])
        buffer.append(TimedData(t, data))
        timestamps.append(t)  # Track the timestamp of each measurement appended
        time.sleep(APPEND_INTERVAL)

        # Stop after the test duration
        if time.time() - start_time >= TEST_DURATION:
            stop_event.set()


def process_measurements(buffer: RingBuffer,
                         stop_event: multiprocessing.Event,
                         timestamps: multiprocessing.Manager().list):
    """Process that retrieves and processes measurements every 100ms, verifying order and continuity."""
    last_time = 0
    retrieved_times = []

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        measurements = buffer.get_measurements_after_time(last_time)
        if measurements:
            # Check continuity and update `last_time`
            for measurement in measurements:
                retrieved_times.append(measurement.t)
            last_time = measurements[-1].t

            # Sleep to simulate processing
            time.sleep(PROCESS_INTERVAL)


    # Assertions after process completes
    assert len(retrieved_times) <= len(
        timestamps), "Retrieved more timestamps than written"
    assert len(retrieved_times) >= len(timestamps) - PROCESS_INTERVAL / APPEND_INTERVAL
    for i, (rt, tt) in enumerate(zip(retrieved_times[:-2], timestamps[:-2])):
        if abs(rt - tt) > 1e-7 * rt:
            print(f"{i}: {rt} != {tt} - {retrieved_times[i-2:i+2], timestamps[i-2:i+2]}")
    assert np.allclose(retrieved_times, timestamps[:len(retrieved_times)]), "Mismatch between retrieved and written timestamps"
    dt = np.diff(retrieved_times)
    print(f"Avg dt: {np.mean(dt)}, Std: {np.std(dt)}")
    assert np.all(np.diff(dt) < 2 * APPEND_INTERVAL), "Written time stamps are not at the correct timing"
    assert abs(len(retrieved_times) - TEST_DURATION / APPEND_INTERVAL) < 0.01 / APPEND_INTERVAL, f"Written only {len(retrieved_times)}, expected {TEST_DURATION / APPEND_INTERVAL}"
    print(
        f"All {len(retrieved_times)} timestamps are consistent between written and retrieved measurements.")


def run_double_ringbuffer_test():
    size = 100000  # Ring buffer size
    buffer = RingBuffer(size, Measurement.dim())

    # Shared event and manager list for tracking data
    stop_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    timestamps = manager.list()  # Track appended timestamps

    # Start append and processing processes
    append_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=append_measurements,
                                          args=(buffer, stop_event, timestamps))
    process_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_measurements, args=(
    buffer, stop_event, timestamps))

    append_proc.start()
    process_proc.start()

    try:
        # Wait for both processes to finish after the specified test duration
        append_proc.join()
        process_proc.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        stop_event.set()
        append_proc.terminate()
        process_proc.terminate()

    print("Test completed successfully.")


